# rundeck unable to auth against Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, rundeck

I'm trying to setup rundeck so that it authenticates against Active Directory

I keep getting this error

[image]

The wiki contains information about the `403. Reason: !role` error
https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/wiki/FAQ#i-get-an-error-logging-in-http-error-403--reason-role

Rundeck 2.6.2-1 (installed from .deb)
Ubuntu 14.04

jaas-ldap.conf

```
ldap {
    com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule required
    debug="true"
    contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
    providerUrl="ldap://DC01.example.com:389"
    bindDn="cn=rundeck,OU=MyOU,DC=example,DC=com"
    bindPassword="correct-horse-battery-staple"
    authenticationMethod="simple"
    forceBindingLogin="true"
    userBaseDn="DC=example,DC=com"
    userRdnAttribute="sAMAccountName"
    userIdAttribute="sAMAccountName"
    userPasswordAttribute="unicodePwd"
    userObjectClass="user"
    roleBaseDn="DC=example,DC=com"
    roleNameAttribute="sAMAccountName"
    roleUsernameMemberAttribute="cn"
    roleMemberAttribute="member"
    roleObjectClass="group"
    cacheDurationMillis="300000"
    supplementalRoles="user"
    reportStatistics="true"
    timeoutRead="10000"
    timeoutConnect="20000"
    nestedGroups="true";
};
```

/var/lib/rundeck/exp/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
    ...
    <security-role>
            <role-name>Enterprise Admins</role-name>
    </security-role>
    ...
```

profile

```
...
export RDECK_JVM="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/rundeck/jaas-ldap.conf \
    -Dloginmodule.name=ldap \
...
```

I'm aware this is goes against best practices for the following reasons:

- Uses "simple" authentication and port 389. All passwords sent in plain text!!!
- baseDN are way too broad, should be narrowed down to speed up ldap search
- Don't need a bindDN if using forceBindingLogin

Additional resources:

https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/590
https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/620
http://www.bitester.com/2015/12/ldap-authentication-with-rundeck.html

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that at least in my use case I had to remove `roleUsernameMemberAttribute`

It is also important to have     `supplementalRoles` defined

The final working example (unoptimized)

```
ldap {
    com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule required
    debug="true"
    contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
    providerUrl="ldap://DC01.example.com:389"
    bindDn="cn=rundeck,OU=MyOU,DC=example,DC=com"
    bindPassword="correct-horse-battery-staple"
    authenticationMethod="simple"
    forceBindingLogin="true"
    userBaseDn="DC=example,DC=com"
    userRdnAttribute="sAMAccountName"
    userIdAttribute="sAMAccountName"
    userPasswordAttribute="unicodePwd"
    userObjectClass="user"
    roleBaseDn="DC=example,DC=com"
    roleNameAttribute="sAMAccountName"
    roleMemberAttribute="member"
    roleObjectClass="group"
    cacheDurationMillis="300000"
    supplementalRoles="user"
    reportStatistics="true"
    timeoutRead="10000"
    timeoutConnect="20000"
    nestedGroups="true";
};
```

Note: This only does ldap authentication. You can also have a hybrid of local accounts and ldap accounts.

**Update**

Additional documentation & information in [this github issue](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1397#issuecomment-189417279)

Comment: Just FYI, `authenticationMethod="simple"` coupled with a port of 389 means you're sending your credentials across the network in clear text.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll update the question to make this more apparent.

Comment: I was getting a completely different error, but by using the config in your answer I was able to get it working, and could build from there. THANK YOU.